How to solve linker issue /usr/bin/ld: undefined references when linking oracle libraries
How can I build the following mwe?
$ g++ -o stackoverflow stackoverflow.cpp   -I/home/myuser/Downloads
/instantclient_23_6/sdk/include   -L/home/myuser/Downloads/instantclient_23_6   -l:libclntsh.so.23.1 -l:libocci.so.23.1
/usr/bin/ld: /home/myuser/Downloads/instantclient_23_6/libocci.so.23.1: undefined reference to `OCILobGetLength'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/myuser/Downloads/instantclient_23_6/libocci.so.23.1: undefined reference to `OCILobArrayWrite'
...

$ cat stackoverflow.cpp
#include <occi.h>

using namespace oracle::occi;
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // Database connection details
    string user = "mwe";
    string password = "mwe";
    string connectString = "itsonlyamwe";

    Environment *env = nullptr;

    env = Environment::createEnvironment(Environment::DEFAULT);

    return 0;
}

$ ls /home/myuser/Downloads/instantclient_23_6
BASIC_LICENSE    glogin.sql         libclntsh.so.21.1      libclntshcore.so.22.1  libocci.so.20.1  network      ucp17.jar
BASIC_README     legacy.so          libclntsh.so.22.1      libclntshcore.so.23.1  libocci.so.21.1  ojdbc11.jar  uidrvci
SDK_LICENSE      libclntsh.so       libclntsh.so.23.1      libnnz.so              libocci.so.22.1  ojdbc17.jar  xstreams.jar
SDK_README       libclntsh.so.10.1  libclntshcore.so       libocci.so             libocci.so.23.1  ojdbc8.jar
SQLPLUS_LICENSE  libclntsh.so.11.1  libclntshcore.so.12.1  libocci.so.10.1        libociei.so      pkcs11.so
SQLPLUS_README   libclntsh.so.12.1  libclntshcore.so.18.1  libocci.so.11.1        libocijdbc23.so  sdk
adrci            libclntsh.so.18.1  libclntshcore.so.19.1  libocci.so.12.1        libsqlplus.so    sqlplus
fips.so          libclntsh.so.19.1  libclntshcore.so.20.1  libocci.so.18.1        libsqlplusic.so  ucp.jar
genezi           libclntsh.so.20.1  libclntshcore.so.21.1  libocci.so.19.1        libtfojdbc1.so   ucp11.jar

$ ll /home/myuser/Downloads/instantclient_23_6/libocci.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 myuser myuser 15 Dec  3 12:13 /home/myuser/Downloads/instantclient_23_6/libocci.so -> libocci.so.23.1*

$ ll /home/myuser/Downloads/instantclient_23_6/libclntsh.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 myuser myuser 17 Dec  3 12:13 /home/myuser/Downloads/instantclient_23_6/libclntsh.so -> libclntsh.so.23.1*

$ ls /home/myuser/Downloads/instantclient_23_6/sdk/include
jzndom.h    nzt.h          oci.h     ocidfn.h      odci.h      oraxml.hpp  oro.h       xmldf.h     xmlsoap.h
jznerr.h    occi.h         oci1.h    ociextp.h     ons.h       oraxmlcg.h  ort.h       xmlerr.h    xmlsoap.hpp
jznev.h     occiAQ.h       oci8dp.h  ocijson.h     opmnlist.h  oraxsd.h    xa.h        xmlev.h     xmlsoapc.hpp
jznotn.h    occiCommon.h   ociap.h   ocikpr.h      orajson.h   oraxsd.hpp  xml.h       xmlotn.h    xmlurl.h
jzntypes.h  occiControl.h  ociapr.h  ociver.h      orastruc.h  ori.h       xml.hpp     xmlotn.hpp  xmlxptr.h
ldap.h      occiData.h     ocidef.h  ocixmldb.h    oratypes.h  orid.h      xmlctx.hpp  xmlproc.h   xmlxsl.h
nzerror.h   occiObjects.h  ocidem.h  ocixstream.h  oraxml.h    orl.h       xmldav.h    xmlsch.h    xmlxvm.h

I got the libraries and include files from the oracle download page.
I have read /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldlib /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcblas /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack the installation of the dev packages is the sdk extraction. The result is shown above.
ChatGPT suggested trying full paths like
g++ -o occi_demo occi_demo.cpp \
  -I/home/myuser/Downloads/instantclient_23_6/sdk/include \
  /home/myuser/Downloads/instantclient_23_6/libclntsh.so \
  /home/myuser/Downloads/instantclient_23_6/libocci.so

however, this gave the same linking failure.
$ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS"

